# Automatically updating geometry attributes in QGIS without using Virtual Fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line, editing, length

I have a line layer and I computed the attribute `"length"` with the field calculator. After that, I changed the geometry of some lines with the editing toolbar. That means the values of "length" in the attribute table are not correct anymore. Is there an automatic way (or at least a quick way) to update the values of `"length"` to the correct actual length of the line geometries?

I know I could update the values using the field calculator. I also know I could use a virtual field. But I want to have the best out of these two options. I would like to have the automatic updates (like virtual fields) and the fact of having the correct values in the geodata itself instead of having these correct values only in my QGIS Project file (`.qgz`).

I observed that my coworkers do many mistakes using the field calculator, that's why I am looking for another solution.

Comment: I haven't used the AutoFields plugin so you can run your own tests: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields.  I do use the calculate geometry plugin which puts a menu item when one right clicks a layer.  It's faster and less likely to make a mistake than using the field calculator.  If you use file geodatabases the shape_length field should auto-update when you save your edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

1. Properties layer -> attribute form -> choose attribute where you need length ->Defaults -> put default value: $length -> check "apply default value on update"

Now when you make new line then value automaticly generate length line, when you modify line - length changing too :)

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks!