# Polygon on scratch or shapefile area returns null in QGIS & EPSG3857

Tags: qgis, area, null

Just got started with QGIS (the software) today and I'm getting Null for a hand-drawn polygon, even for a circle shape.  Here is what I've done:

1. Installed QuickMapServices plugin
2. Installed GeoCoding plugin
3. Created new Project
4. Added ESRI Satellite ArcGIS/WorldImagery 3857 layer
5. Added Scratch Temp layer also 3857 (later a shapefile layer)
6. Proceeded to draw an irregular hand-drawn polygon (later circle)
7. Added area field, decimal, 10, 2
8. Open attribute table but resulting area is NULL

As mentioned I've tried creating a shapefile layer and drawing a simple circle shape as well with the same area field params but still get NULL.

Not sure if its relevant but I'm following this video tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vwQ0o_t4XQ

Did I miss a parameter somewhere that I needed to configure?

Comment: Just adding a field called "Area" doesn't automatically tell QGIS to calculate the area.  You can use the field calculator to calculate the area.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30008/2856 but note that EPSG:3857 is a poor choice for calculating areas and will give you very inaccurate results, particularly at higher latitudes. Suggest you use an equal-area CRS appropriate for your area of interest.

Comment: Ok i figured out I had to create the field using the calculator and selecting the $area function.  Now is there a way to have it update the area after i edit the polygon? Cause I find myself having to update it manually with the field calculator.

Comment: Which CRS do you suggest for more accurate readings?

Comment: An equal-area or UTM CRS appropriate for *your* area of interest, look at epsg.io. Re update, https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389727

Comment: Is your area field a virtual field or an actual field?